# Convert Vertically Stacked video to horizontally stacked via FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Based on the answer to [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/convert-horizontal-side-by-side-to-vertically-stacked-3d-video?newreg=5ad754b5b60d46fc80546d15fb66b35c), how would the command line

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 [top]; \ 
[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0[bottom]; \
[top][bottom]vstack[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

be changed to do the opposite, split two stacked images (3240x2160) to one 6840x1080 video?

Answer (score 1):

You would crop the full width and half-height. Then use hstack to join them.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw:ih/2:0:0 [left]; \
[0:v]crop=iw:ih/2:0:ih/2[right]; \
[left][right]hstack[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

Comment: I get this error:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fa2a2402b00] No such filter: ' '
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
I assume there is a syntax error in there somewhere?

Comment: There was a trailing space in your original command (2nd line) which got copied over - removed it.